# Difference between photoluminescence spectra, scattering and absorption of light by a nano particle?

Tags: scattering, spectroscopy, absorption

If light is incident on a nano-particle, then what are the differences between the phenomena that occurs afterwards such as scattering, absorption and photoluminescence (PL) spectra. Though I know about scattering and absorption phenomena, I do not understand the phenomena of PL spectra with scattering and absorption. So far I know that PL spectra is when particle absorbs light, and the electron in that particle goes to higher states, after some time the electrons emit the photon and come to the lower state and we get PL spectra. If I am right, then does the PL spectra occurs after the absorption process? If so, then what is difference between scattering spectra and PL spectra. Also, how can we measure this PL spectra using lumerical fdtd or other types of software (I know how to measure scattering in lumerical fdtd) ?
Pardon me for this un-organized way of asking questions.

Comment: Can you add what you mean by PL spectra to the question? Is that photoluminescence?

Comment: @Newbie Yes, exactly, it's photo-luminescenece.